# Progress Dialog with AsyncTask + Drawer Layout not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, drawerlayout

I am working in an application where I have several  network requests between activities and all of them the ProgressDialog shows and work normally... Except the first one. My guess is that is because I have a Drawer Layout implemented and that is "blocking" the Dialog...

I have tried dismissing the drawer before the request but that still doesn't works :(

```
// This is called when someone clicks in an item from the drawer layout
// "this" is passed and fetched as Context for the ProgressDialog
amr = new AvailableModelRequest(this,ss,this.getFilesDir(), modelType);
... more stuff goes here to handle the result from the Request.

// Inside the AvailableModelRequest...

loader.execute(MESSAGE_TYPE);

// The AsyncTask that handles the network request and showing the dialog
private class DataLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog pD = new ProgressDialog(context);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("INSIDE PRE EXECUTE!: ", "HELLO DIALOG!!");
        pD.setTitle("Loading");
        pD.setMessage("Gathering information...");
        pD.setIndeterminate(false);
        pD.setCancelable(false);
        pD.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... message) {
        // Network stuff happens
    }

    /**
     * Look for errors in the server operations
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        // do stuff based on the success or not
        pD.dismiss();
    }
```

I have similar requests through the application and all of them works just fine... except this one :(

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Edit: So I took of the Drawer layout and for some reason this Dialog is still not loading :(